# d3js: scatterplot zoom. Only axis is zooming not the data

Tags: javascript, html, css, csv, d3.js

tried to create a scatterplot which can be zoomed but only the axis is getting zoomed and not the data. Not able to figure out whats wrong anybody any help with this one?.

github link of project : [scatterplot with zoom](https://github.com/bhargavavn/Scatterplot_zoom.git)

Comment: please add code example to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two separate issues with the way the zoom is working:

1. You are not selecting the `<circle>`s (points in the scatter plot) correctly when zooming. Consequently when you zoom only the axes are changing (as you described). An easy way to fix this is to give each `<circle>` a class (e.g. `class="dot"`), and then use that to select them.

   First add the class="dot" to each of your circles (line ~140):

   ```
   svg.selectAll("dot")
           .data(data)
           .enter().append("circle")
           .attr("class", "dot")
   ```

   Then update the `function zoom` to select them correctly (line ~195):

   ```
   svg.selectAll(".dot") // <---- select all circles with class "dot"
           .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
           .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); });
   ```
2. Right now the zoom only occurs when you try to zoom in on an axis or individual point. If you want a user to be able to zoom in no matter where their mouse is over your scatter plot, you can add a background `<rect>` that will make sure the zoom event is detected for the SVG.

   ```
   svg.append("rect")
       .style("fill", "#fff")
       .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
       .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   ```

Making these two changes fixes the zoom.

[image: gif of zooming]